# How to get and maintain the oauth2 token using spring-security-oauth2-client when using authorization code grant in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

```
How can I get the token to the front end angular application after successful redirection to the index.html page happens like
1. I have used 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
in my pom.xml
2. then I have added required properties in my application.properties file
3. I built the angular files and placed them under resources/static folder
```

Now the redirection to auth-server and callback to application happens successfully but how to get the oauth2 token and store in the angular application which will be useful for further calls

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Angular app, then it is the **client**. It should use [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) or alike to:

- login users
- handle redirects to and from **authorization-server**
- exchange authorization-code for access-token
- access-token refreshing
- add authorization-header with access-token to requests sent to configured secured routes

Spring REST API applications are **resource-servers**. It should depend on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, not `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. Refer to spring boot doc or have a look at [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for more details on configuring Spring resource-servers.

Comment: Thank you @ch4mp but using angular-auth-oidc-client stores the token in session storage so is it safe to use in angular or to use in spring-boot-starter-oauth2 client

Comment: Read my answer again and pay attention to the Spring libs (not) to use. And yes, `angular-auth-oidc-client` is safe. It is just standard ([certified](https://openid.net/developers/certified/)) OpenID client implementation. In OAuth2 standard, requests authorization is not the responsibility of the resource server, it is client responsibility. Period.

Comment: Resource server just checks that request Authorization meets its expectations (roles, audience, scope, or whatever was attached to the access token by the Authorization server when client authenticated)

Comment: sure thanks @ch4mp, it helped me clarify my doubt